# Detecting mouse movement starting and stopping with an Observable / Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

Let me start with:

1. I'm totally new to Rx
2. I'm out of practice with C# / Linq
3. I'm experimenting/learning so there's no *application use* to this question

I've read some introductory content, including this [Introduction to the Reactive Framework](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/11/13/introduction-to-the-reactive-framework-part-iii/) by *Matthew Podwysocki*.

So I've started out with one of his examples and written some *mouse-drag/line-drawing* code like this:

```
var leftMouseDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(mainCanvas, "MouseLeftButtonDown");
var leftMouseUp = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>(mainCanvas, "MouseLeftButtonUp");
var mouseMove = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(mainCanvas, "MouseMove");

var mouseMoves = from mm in mouseMove
                 let location = mm.EventArgs.GetPosition(mainCanvas)
                 select new { location.X, location.Y };

var mouseDiffs = mouseMoves.Skip(1).Zip(mouseMoves, (l, r) => new { X1 = l.X, Y1 = l.Y, X2 = r.X, Y2 = r.Y });

var mouseDrag = from _ in leftMouseDown
                from md in mouseDiffs.TakeUntil(leftMouseUp)
                select md;

var mouseSub = mouseDrag.Subscribe(item =>
{
     var line = new Line
     {
         Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue,
         X1 = item.X1,
         X2 = item.X2,
         Y1 = item.Y1,
         Y2 = item.Y2,
         StrokeThickness = 5
     };
     mainCanvas.Children.Add(line);
 });
```

**My question**

Based on playing with that example, I'd like to try reacting to mouse movement, such that:

- when the mouse is moving, I set the background colour of `someCanvas` to green
- when the mouse is not moving, I set the background colour to red

Left mouse button is *not* involved, just the mouse movement.

Is that possible?

Comment: Don't miss the fantastic http://www.introtorx.com/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key here is when is the mouse not moving?  When it has been idle for 1 second, 10 seconds, 250 milliseconds?  The following should do what you want.  It is an observable of type `bool`.  It yields `true` when the mouse is moving and `false` if the mouse is idle longer than the specified idle time.

```
int idleTime = 1000;

var mouseMoving =
    mouseMove
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(idleTime), 1) // Buffer the mouse move events for the duration of the idle time.
    .Select(x => x.Any())                           // Return true if the buffer is not empty, false otherwise.
    .DistinctUntilChanged();                        // Only notify when the mouse moving state changes.
```

<s>I will be the first to tell you that I suspect this is not the best solution.  It seems needlessly wasteful to buffer mouse move events.  I tried to find a solution using `Sample` but I was unable to make that work.</s>?

I am much more comfortable with the updated solution thanks to Jerry's comment.

Comment: I think that if you also pass in a capacity limit of 1 to the buffer, then you will get a more responsive result.  As soon as the buffer has anything in it, we know you should emit false and start the time-limited buffer over again.

Comment: @Jerry - Well look at that.  I completely missed the fact that there is an overload that takes a duration and window size.  Thanks.

Comment: @JasonBoyd thanks. I also don't know if it's the best solution, but has given me info to consider and helped my learning (hence upvote). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a problem here:

```
var mouseDiffs = mouseMoves.Skip(1)
    .Zip(mouseMoves, (l, r) => new { X1 = l.X, Y1 = l.Y, X2 = r.X, Y2 = r.Y });
```

When an observer subscribes to `mouseDiffs`, *two* subscriptions are made to `mouseMoves`. You should use `Publish` instead to ensure only a single subscription to `mouseMoves` per subscription to `mouseDiffs`:

```
var mouseDiffs = mouseMoves.Publish(obs => obs.Skip(1)
    .Zip(obs, (l, r) => new { X1 = l.X, Y1 = l.Y, X2 = r.X, Y2 = r.Y }));
```

Now let's define an observable of colors for your canvas. Note you don't actually need your `mouseDiffs` observable - `mouseMove` will work fine for this.

```
var colors = mouseMove
    .Select(_ => Observable.Concat(
        Observable.Return(true),
        Observable.Return(false).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))))
    .Switch()
    .StartWith(false)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Select(isActive => isActive ? Color.Green : Color.Red);
```

You can `Subscribe` to `colors` and set your canvas color each time it emits a `Color`.

Comment: thanks for the info regarding `Publish`... I tried the `colors` observable from your answer but it doesn't ever emit *red*. (I think) in order to get a new mouse move (and an update to `mouseDiffs`), either `x` or `y` must be different to the previous `x` / `y` values?

Comment: @GavinHope Oh I see - you don't get any mouse move events unless the mouse moved! I will update the answer to use a timeout behavior instead.

Comment: in this context, is the use of `_` (underscore) simply convention?

Comment: @GavinHope The underscore is a convention for indicating a lambda parameter is unused. I ignore the `MouseEventArgs` passed into the lambda.